# Удалённая база данных андроид

Tags: android, база-данных

Учусь разработке приложений на андроид (на Android studio работаю). Создаю приложение где необходимо регистрация пользователя, вопрос как сделать удаленную базу данных, чтоб авторизация происходила только при включённом интернете? И как связать ее с gmail

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.. См. «[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)» для прояснения ситуации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Арендовать сервер у хостинг-провайдера. Либо самый простой статический хостинг и писать бэкенд на PHP + MySQL или полноценный VPS на Linux, на котором уже можно и любую БД брать (Postgresql, например) и бэкэнд писать на Spring, запуская его под Tomcat.
2. Создать в БД нужные таблицы.
3. Создать API на `PHP` или `Spring`
4. С клиента (мобильное приложение) через `Retrofit` слать запросы на ваш сервер, который будет писать/читать из БД.
5. Почту подключить можно либо гугловую либо собственную типа `myname@mydomain.myzone`. Для этого обычно берут специальную библиотеку под нужный язык и передают оной параметры подключения. В случае гугла надо будет ещё пароль специальный получать если включена двухфакторная авторизация. А также авторизоваться в гугле с IP сервера (например прокинув нужный порт на личный компьютер через ssh)